# Sum based on specific condition - Oracle

Tags: oracle, sum

I need your advice on the following query that I have - Let's say that I have a table with all payments that are booked on my current account. 
The details of the payment contain date of the operation and hour. I would like to extract the information in a such a way so to have next to each transaction the amount of of the balance(sum of transactions' amount) since the beginning of the day up to the current transaction. The balance for each day is reset to 0.

I was thinking to join this table to itself and find all unique operations from the joined table where the date matches and the hour is less then currently reviewed operation's hour then to use sum on the group.

Still I think that there is much more intelligent solution.

Thanks in advance

[here is a sample of the table. Expected result is in the last column](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9f857/1/0)

Comment: I don't see your query.

Comment: Please include sample table structure and data. You could use SQLFiddle.com to show us the structure and data. Also include expected results in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you just want a rolling sum.  Making up column names and table names, you probably want something like this in your projection (your `select` list).  You shouldn't need to do a self-join.

```
SUM(transaction_amount) 
  OVER (PARTITION BY account_number, trunc(transaction_date)
            ORDER BY transaction_date) rolling_sum
```